# Searching in an ArrayList Vs Inserting and selecting from Sqllite

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

In my Android App, I need to get the JSON object from a server. There will be around 2000 JSON objects. I have around 30 String values in a ArrayList. I need to check the 2000 JSON objects and get those 30 values which is there in ArrayList.

**Question**

Option # 1 - Searching the JSON objects in 30 different Asynchronous calls

Option # 2 - Multi insert into SQLLite and run a SQL to fetch the 30 Values.

Which one will be good in performance Option #1 (or) Option # 2

Comment: Option # 3, request a list instead of each one separated. The Option#2 is good if you do need to persist the data already for offline access.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos only JSON is possible. So with JSON Option #2 is preferred ?

Comment: I mean, instead of asking each item for the server, request the whole 30 ids you want and it return a JSON list.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Not possible.. As the link will give only the JSON of all at one shot. Else there is an option of firing 30 different Https request https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=INR&limit=2000

Comment: If not possible then how is #1 viable?

Comment: Option # 1 is possible. As the call  api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=INR&limit=2000 will give 2000 JSON objects . I wll catch those JSON objects in Array list and check it in 30 different Asynchronous calls for 30 different values